# Determine how many integers, starting from the number 1, need to be added so that the sum will equal more than 100? Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a solution to this task "Determine how many integers, starting from the number 1, need to be added so that the sum will equal more than 100."using JavaScript.
I have my solution but I tend to feel that it is wrong.
Could you please help me?

I do not even realize if I understand the task in the right way.
Please see my solution below:

```
<script>

let result = 0;
for ( i = 1; i<20; i++){
  result+=i;
  if( result>100) {
    break
  }
}
console.log(i)

</script>
```

Output is 14, It is right , but  I am not sure in the way I solving it.

Comment: Ur solution is correct ... however you should use a while loop if you are not sure about the number of iterations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works, there is nothing wrong about it. 
You could simplify it, for example use a `while` rather than a `for` loop :

```js
let total = 0
let count = 1;
// we loop until total is greater or equals to 100.
while(total < 100) {
  // add the current count to the total
  total += count;
  // increment the count.
  count++;
}

// we need to account for the last ++;
console.log(count - 1);
```

Here the `while` loop will run until the condition is broken.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Could you please clarify the last code line. Why do we need subtract one in this part of code? (console.log(count - 1)

Comment: The last line of code is used to show the output. We are removing one to the total because before exiting the loop, it will increment the `count` variable. so our result will be off by one.

Answer (score 1):

`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + k` is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

It can be solved using [image: (x² + x) / 2 = n] and then [image: x² + x -2n = 0](![(x² + x) / 2 = n].
There, n is 100 and x is the base of the triangle (k in the above example, i in your loop).

This is a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation), solved using :

[image: a * x² + b * x + c = 0](![(x² + x) / 2 = n]

[image: x = (-b +/- sqrt(b² - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)]

if we replace a b c by their respective values, we get :

[image: x = (-1 +/- sqrt(1² - 4 * 1 * (-200))) / (2 * 1)]

`x = 13.6509716981` or `x = -14.6509716981` depending of the sign we use

If you round up `13.6509716981` you get 14, the expected result

This is written `Math.ceil((-1 + Math.sqrt(1 - 4 * 1 * (-2 * num))) / 2)` in JS, `num` being the value to reach (100 in your example)

This can be shortened to `Math.ceil((-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * num)) / 2)`

```js
// Your original code, as reference
function FindNumberUsingLoops(num)
{
  let result = 0;
  // I modified the loop exit condition to make sure every case will run
  for ( i = 1; i < num; i++){
    result+=i;
    if( result>=num) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

function FindNumber(num)
{
  return Math.ceil((-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * num)) / 2);
}

console.log("using equation : " + FindNumber(100));
console.log("using loops : " + FindNumberUsingLoops(100));

console.log("using equation : " + FindNumber(500));
console.log("using loops : " + FindNumberUsingLoops(500));

console.log("using equation : " + FindNumber(42));
console.log("using loops : " + FindNumberUsingLoops(42));

console.log("using equation : " + FindNumber(1000));
console.log("using loops : " + FindNumberUsingLoops(1000));

console.log("using equation : " + FindNumber(1000000000000000000));
// uncomment below, this takes few seconds to solve
// console.log("using loops : " + FindNumberUsingLoops(1000000000000000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
let cheker = 0;
for (i = 1; i; i++) {
    cheker += i;
    if (cheker <= 100) {
        console.log(i, cheker); // sum before 100 (94) and integers before 100 (13)
    } else {
        console.log(i, cheker); // sum after 100 (105) and integers before 100 (14 - answer)
        break;
    }
}
```